# Index out of bounds exception in homework

Tags: java, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to do a homework assignment. I have to use dynamic programming to display whether the next person to move is in a win/loss state. I don't need help with the actual problem, I need help with an index out of bounds exception I'm getting that baffles me. I'm only going to paste part of my code here, because I only need the for loops looked at. I also don't want anyone in my class seeing all my code and copying it. If you need more data please let me know. So here is the code:

```
if(primeArray[x] == true){
    for(int i = 1; i <= x; i++){
        if(primeArray[i]== true){
            newRowNumber = x - i;
        }
        if(dynaProgram[newRowNumber][columnNumber] < minimum){
            minimum = dynaProgram[newRowNumber][columnNumber];
        }
    }
}
//COMPOSITE CASE FOR X!
else{
    for(int k = 1; k <= x; k++){
        if((primeArray[k] == false)){
            newRowNumber = x - k;
        }
        if(dynaProgram[newRowNumber][columnNumber] < minimum){
            minimum = dynaProgram[newRowNumber][columnNumber];
        }
    }
```

For some reason the `if(primeArray[i] == true` runs correctly, but I'm getting index out of bounds exception on `if(primeArray[k] == false`. The only difference between these two is the use of the variable k over i in the for loop.(the for loops are identical) I haven't used either variables anywhere else in my code. I have no idea why this occurs for one but not the other. In both cases, x remains the same number.

I am also getting an index out of bounds exception on the second `minimum = dynaProgram[newRowNumber][columnNumber]`, while the first doesn't encounter an error. I know it's probably a stupid error, but I can't figure it out. If I change the 'k' for loop to `k < x` the index of out bounds exception in the `if(primeArray[k] == false` line goes away, but then it isn't correct. (The error on the second `minimum = dynaProgram[newRowNumber][columnNumber]` doesn't go away however.)

All this code is in a nested for loop which iterates through the rows and columns in the table to fill them in. If I remove the above code and just put `dynaProgram[rowNumber][columnNumber] = 1` I don't have an issue, so I don't believe that is the problem.

Comment: i suggest you, debug the code and arrest the exception

Comment: yes, try to run the code with Debugger under Eclipse.

Comment: my first guess is that the not shown outer loop cycles x from 1 to x<=primearray.length, and not from 0 to x<primearray.length. if thats the case you need to correct that and adjust each inner loop to start with 0 and go until i < x

Comment: I figured it out. See my comment to the person who responded below to see what the issue was if your interested. Thanks for the help. I apprciate it.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing an array of length 5 (for example)

```
int[] fred = new int[5];
```

the first element will be `fred[0]` and the last will be `fred[4]`

So when doing something like:

```
    if(primeArray[i]== true){
```

Make sure that `i` is less than the array length.  Using a value of `i` equal to the array length will throw an exception.

Comment: Wow, yeah. I made a stupid mistake. So the reason why its not an issue the first time, but it is a second time is because the different loops are in an if...else statement. It's not checking if(primeArray[i] = true) for i=x because i is a composite number if i=x and so its running the else part. If x where a prime number, I would be getting an error on the opposite loop. It's been a long day. Just did a 3 hour practice putman exam. I think I'm going to break for the night, lol. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry guys, don't have 15 reputation yet. I just joined, so I can't rate your comments up yet.><